# Will 13.10 format a usb stick native via "Files"?

Tags: 13.10, usb-drive, format, filemanager

I plug in the drive, "Files" opens. Right click on the drive, select format, choose ntfs (or fat or ext4) click format again, all the boxes go away and nothing is done.
User has read/write permission, can't reset permissions for groups or other even after entering the password.
Used gparted and got it done, but the option is there and doesn't work. What's broken?
I've tried several usb 2.0 flash drives, they all read and write fine, pretty sure it's not a hardware thing.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Any app that requires root privileges should ask for it (as most of them do). If it does not it is a bug. Remember - Ubuntu was meant to be the Linux for users that do not know command line. I know how to install and run gparted, but my girlfriend just wants to format her pen-drive and when she cannot do this it is a huge dishonour for Linux as a human friendly OS. I mean the problem is just another bug, but your answer is just pathetic. Come on it's 2014, not 1995. Sending users to command line is not the way Linux want to be. Maybe it's time to install some other Linux di

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing broken.

To format a partition, you need to have write access to the partition file in `/dev`. This can only be done as superuser (root). You should've noticed that GParted asked you for your password. At this moment you granted the program root permissions.

Nautilus, or any other file browser/manager, is run with user permissions by default, so it can read and write to the *mounted stick directory*, but not to the device file itself, which it would have to do in order to format the partition. To run Nautilus with superuser permissions, open a terminal and enter `gksudo nautilus`.