# USB stick format via Nautilus

Tags: usb, nautilus, format

Okay, so I was fooling around on Ubuntu 13.10, then noticed that when I right-click my USB stick in Nautilus, I have a "Format" option.

When I click "Format", a new window opens and asks for what to do. I choose my options, then click on "Format".

And then, nothing appends... My USB drive is not formatted, and I don't have anything asking for my password.

I looked around, and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396052/will-13-10-format-a-usb-stick-native-via-files), which is not helping, since the "Format" option on right-click does not appear with nautilus started as super-user.

Any thoughts ?

Please note that I'm not trying to format my USB-stick, I'm trying to format it with the built-in nautilus action.

EDIT : 
The "Format" option in context menu is provided by gnome-disks. Gnome-disks can't format my drive either. So far, I've found using it one error `Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)`

Comment: Mint team built their own tool, maybe it could be used without nemo, by redirecting the binary of that nautilus action to the mint tool (available through PPA and in .deb) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok well, I found it. But it's messy...

My error was caused by `util-linux`(in buggy version 2.20 since 2012), which is needed by `udisks`, which is the package used by `gnome-disks` to format USB drives, which is the tool used by the "Format" option in the Nautilus context-menu.

The bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/1059872) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081?comments=all). It has not be solved since 2012.

Thats a bummer...

EDIT : and if you want my advice, DO NOT try to build util-linux yourself^^ I just did, following all recommendations and without any warnings, and I bricked my system.

Comment: "DO NOT try to build util-linux [...] I bricked my system"

I'm intrigued. Did you `sudo make install` by chance?

Comment: wow, it's been 3 years, I have absolutely no idea, sorry :D from what I wrote back then , it seems I found some guide to build it (or maybe a readme on the sources?) and at some point in there, it broke the world. I can't really help you more than that :/