# Why Nautilus can not format Bootable USB?

Tags: nautilus, gparted, usb-drive, format

I know I can format Bootable USB drives with gparted or software like that. I do it every time I need to.

But I want to know why nautilus can not format that? Is there any logic behind it?

I searched many sites but the only thing I found was How to format it with gparted or software like that.

Comment: I am not sure what you want, make a USB drive bootable or erase a formerly bootable USB drive to use it for regular storage again?

Comment: @ByteCommander I want to know what is the logic behind the Nautilus that can not "erase a formerly bootable USB drive to use it for regular storage".

Comment: I do not have a device ready for testing at the moment, but I assume that Nautilus can only format partitions. However, a bootable USB is no longer just a single partition, it can be multiple. It also has a partition table and boot sector stuff, which might cause the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Nautilus uses [some tools under the hood](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414979/usb-stick-format-via-nautilus), and one of those tools may have problems with some partition tables and or file systems.
- It is a good idea to use a dedicated tool like **gparted** to create or edit the partition table and file systems (alias formating).
- Some versions of gparted has problems with the iso 9660 file system, that you get, when you clone an Ubuntu iso file to a USB pendrive or memory card. When that happens you can use **mkusb** to wipe the first megabyte or restore it to a standard storage device,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)